# Logic of installation location of R packages under Linux

Tags: linux, r

What's the logic behind the different installation locations of various R packages?  I seem to have packages installed in several different locations on my linux machine.  Is this typical behavior and if so what is the rational for installing a package in `/usr/lib/R/library` vs `/usr/lib/R/site-library`?  I don't really care where the package is installed but it does seem kind of silly to have the installations spread out in different locations across my system.

`Renviron` has the comment below, which seems to suggest that `/usr/lib/R/site-library` is for Debian packaged packages, but doesn't really explain the purpose of the other two directories.  Also, by setting `/usr/lib/R/library` last in the list doesn't that make it not the default dir for `install.packages()`?

```
# edd Apr 2003  Allow local install in /usr/local, also add a directory for
#               Debian packaged CRAN packages, and finally the default dir 


> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Matt,

You generalize the wrong way from the specific (Debian/Ubuntu) to the generic (all Linux distros).

This particular setup was suggested to me by two Debian-using R Core members (and this was before the dawn of Ubuntu).  This is *not* an R-wide recommendation which is why you will not find it in the manuals, but rather a specific recommendation by R power users to be implemented on Debian and Debian-alike systems.

The basic idea is

- to remain totally faithful to the separation of `/usr/`, `/var/`, .... to be handled by the *package management system* (eg `apt-get`, `dpkg`, ...) on the one hand, and `/usr/local/...` etc by the user on the other hand: these two shall *never* mix
- so that `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` gets the first spot in the list emitted by `.libPaths()` and thus becomes the default, thus ensuring that user-installed package end up below `/usr/local/` as per the previous point
- so that below `/usr` we get a separation between R's recommended packaged (included in the basic R sources too: `boot`, `grid`, `lattice`, ...) inside `/usr/lib/R/library`, and then all other *package management controlled* `r-cran-*` packages below `/usr/lib/R/site-library`. So e.g. `r-cran-xml` ends up there, or `r-cran-zoo`, or ...

I still think the split is terrific, and that is why I maintain this setup in the Debian R packages.

Having the local packages site-wide for all users is a good idea on a multi-user operating system.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I figured that there was probably a reason for the splits that I as a relatively new Linux (Ubuntu) user didn't grasp.